# Which component handles which gesture, swipe or touch event?

Tags: android, android-listview, touch, android-viewpager, swipe

I have a `ViewPager`, containing a few fragments with a `SwipeRefreshLayout` in turn each containing a `ListView`. Each `ListView` contains items that have `onClickListener`s defined, and some of the items also react to somewhat horizontal swipes.

How does the system determine which component gets to handle a particular gesture or touch event?

Comment: Also, interesting question: if you add in the ViewPager something like MapFragment (you can move map up-down-left-right, use single/double tap, rotation gesture) and in this case changing pages will affect only by swiping to left/right from the edge of a screen